# After saving product on frontend, search results disappear

Tags: product, api, catalogsearch

I have an observer that watches the event: `catalog_block_product_list_collection`

When this event triggers my code iterates through the collection, finds the SKU for a certain product, then changes the price and saves.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

public function changePrices(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

    foreach ($collection as $product){
        if ($product->getData('is_api')){

            $parts = new SoapClient("XXXX");
            try{
                $res = $parts->ExactPartLookup([
                    'userName' => 'XXXX',
                    'password' => 'XXXX',
                    'partNumber' => $product->getData('sku'),
                    'make' => $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer_code')
                    ]);
                $price = $res->ExactPartLookupResult->PartInformation_v2->List;
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
                $product->setMinimalPrice($price);
                $product->setPrice($price);
                $product->setFinalPrice($price);
                $product->save();
            }
            catch(SoapFault $e){
                Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, 'errortest.log');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm getting a weird issue when I place a search in my store. The first time I search something, it will show results. However when I refresh that search results page, it will not display any results. If I search for another keyword, it will show results, and then I can search the original keyword again and it will show results.

Here's a video illustrating what's actually happening: 
http://recordit.co/IRnwqbhYUy

I've now introduced the same code into the AdminHtml product grid.
When I set the price on the api products, the products that don't fall within that criteria have an empty string for price. I'm thinking that this is a related issue.

Comment: This code looks fine to me. What I more suspect is the caching mechanism for the search results. What do you see in the `catalogsearch_result` table?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not showing anything in that table. It seems the results aren't being cached, but it's looking for them within the cache?

Comment: I was able to get rid of this issue by setting reindex to manual for the frontend. However, I'm not sure this is the best solution.

Comment: After looking at the code, I am wondering if the issue is with the empty prices. Are you positive that the `$price` variable in the above code is set?

Comment: I'm 100% sure, before using it this way I would set it with a manual number. Also, if the request fails it won't even populate that value.

Comment: @JosephatSwiftOtterStudios any ideas?